# Как вывести двухмерный массив в таблицу

Tags: php, html

Имеется полученный из БД массив, с неизвестным количеством строк.

При запросе:

```
print_r($res)
```

получаем:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [number] => 203 [loc] => Техподдержка [fio] => Сергей Забулдыгин ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [number] => 112 [loc] => Юр. Отдел [fio] => Иван Нечестный ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [number] => 115 [loc] => Чертёжники [fio] => Георгий Криворуков ) )

Каким образом его развернуть в таблицу в цикле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="1">';
  foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($value as $data)
    echo "<td>".$data."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, спасибо:

```
echo "<table>";
foreach ($res as $result){
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($result as $rValue){
                echo "<td>{$rValue}</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```